# File upload to S3 is failing with "No such file found in directory" error

Tags: amazon-web-services

I tried to upload a json file present on my desktop to S3 bucket using `boto3`. I used the code:-

```
s3.Bucket('myfirstbucket').upload_file('myfile.json', 'myfile.json')
```

and

```
s3.Bucket('myfirstbucket').put_object(Key='myfile.json',Body=data)
```

But everytime it gives an error-

> "No such file found in the directory"

I could not figure out the reason for this error. Please guide

Answer (score 1):

I think you should read the doc. This is a good start to get a proper connection to the bucket

```
from boto.s3.key import Key
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

AWS__BUCKET = "your-buckett"
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "your key id"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "your secret key"

from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
conn = S3Connection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
my_bucket = conn.get_bucket(AWS_BUCKET)
```

Now you can send some data

```
k = Key(b)
k.key = 'myfile.json'
k.set_contents_from_filename('myfile.json')
```

More info here: http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/s3_tut.html#storing-data